# Regex Fetch value from string

Tags: java, regex

I am very new to Regex.
I have String from which i tried fetching value.

```
String conditionExpression= "{action==\"Submit\" && orgType== \"supply\"}";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=orgType==)\"[^\"]+\"").matcher(conditionExpression);
if (matcher.find()) {
    orgType = matcher.group().replaceAll("\"", "");
}
```

Input will be String : `"{action=="Submit" && orgType== "supply"}"`
Output will be value of orgType: `supply`

Tried fetching orgType using Regex , but its returning null. Anything wrong here?

Comment: Give input sample and ouput wanted please.

Comment: Please explain in simple english what you are wanting

Comment: If your string `conditionExpression` is `{action=="Submit" && orgType== "supply"}` there is a space  after `==` and your regex does not account for that. You seem to want `"orgType\\s*==\\s*\"([^\"]+)\""` and then `orgType = matcher.group(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for whitespace that may appear around the equals sign. Besides, there is no need to post-process the match value if you use a capturing group around `[^"]+`.

Here is a fixed code:

```
String orgType = "";
String conditionExpression= "{action==\"Submit\" && orgType== \"supply\"}";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("orgType\\s*==\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"").matcher(conditionExpression);
if (matcher.find()) {
  orgType = matcher.group(1);
}
System.out.println(orgType);  // => supply
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/nsMg3U)

The `\\s*==\\s*` part of the pattern matches `==` enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars.

The `([^\"]*)` pattern is a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that pushes a submatch value into Group 1 that you can retrieve via `matcher.group(1)` (no need to remove double quotes later).